# No logro acceder a una etiqueta en iframe contentWindow

Tags: javascript

He intentado de todas las formas intentar acceder a una etiqueta a través de un iframe con el metodo *contentWindow* pero nada, ninguna opción me sirve, solo me da problemas de todo tipo, 'document.getElement... is null' etc.. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

```js
// HE INTENTADO CON

var a = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;
var b = a.document.querySelector(".open");
b.style.color = "red";


// TAMBIÉN CON

var a = document.getElementById("iframe");
var b = a.contentWindow;
var c = b.document.querySelector(".open");
c.style.color = "red";

// CON

var a = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow;
var b = a.document.querySelectorAll(".open");


for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {

b.style.color = "red";

}


// PERO NINGUNA FUNCIONA
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="content"></iframe>
```

Comment: Coloca lo que hay dentro del iframe para ver a que quieres acceder

Comment: Así a voz de pronto, CREO que puede ser lo que me pasa a mi a veces, que no logro ver de buenas a primeras los elementos del DOM:
Tienes que agregar un window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{...}) para poder hacer un querySelector de los elementos en cuestión. Una vez visto el iframe, lo demás vendrá solo